# Well defined function on Lebesgue integration

Tags: definition, lebesgue-integral

I have a partial definition for nonnegative functions. $S$ denotes the class of simple functions $s$ on $\mathbb R^n$ such that $0\leq s(x)<\infty$.

If $s\in S$, then the integral of $s$, denoted  $\int sd\lambda$, is the number given as follows:
if $s$ is presented in the form 
$$s=\sum_{k=1}^m \alpha_k\chi_{A_k}$$
where $0\leq \alpha_k<\infty$ and the sets $A_k$ are measurable and disjoint, then

$$\int sd\lambda =\sum_{k=1}^m \alpha_k \lambda (A_k)$$

Assuming I know that $\int sd\lambda$ is well defined, how can I show that it follows

- $0\leq\int sd\lambda \leq \infty$?
- If $0\leq c<\infty$ is a constant, $\int csd\lambda = c\int sd\lambda$?

Is it that obvious (written in a book)? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly obvious, if the integral is well defined.

Assuming $\lambda $ takes on only positive values or $\infty$, that is. In this case the sum which defines the integral is a finite sum of nonnegative terms, implying the first item.

Then, if
$$s = \sum \alpha_k\chi_{A_k}$$
you have 
$$cs = \sum c\alpha_k\chi_{A_k}$$ so 
$$\int cs d\lambda = \sum c\alpha_k\lambda(A_k) 
=c \sum \alpha_k\lambda(A_k)=c\int s d\lambda$$

Comment: This also shows that $0\leq \int sd\lambda \leq \infty$? If so I am failing to see how. can you kindly expand?

Comment: @havakok I' m not sure what is unclear. You have  $ \int s= \sum \alpha_k\lambda (A_k)$. For each $k$, $0\le\lambda (A_k)\le \infty$ so $0\le\alpha\lambda(A_k)\le \infty$ since $0\le \alpha_k< \infty$, and so is the sum between $0$ and $\infty$

Comment: The $0\leq \lambda (A_k)\leq \infty $ was what i missed. Now it's clear as the day. Thanks a lot.